# Como crear un tablero de damas C#

Tags: c#

estoy intentando crear un tablero en C# que me genere la siguiente estructura:

```
X_X_X
_X_X_
X_X_X
_X_X_
X_X_X
```

con el siguiente código:

```
static int n = 5;

public static void Main() {
  if(n > 10 || n <= 0)
  {
    n = 5;
  }
  int a = n;
  int b = n;
int[,] arrayTablero = new int[a, b];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayTablero.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayTablero.GetLength(1); j++)
    { 
       Console.Write("x" + "_");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
  
  }
```

pero el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
x_x_x_x_x_
x_x_x_x_x_
x_x_x_x_x_
x_x_x_x_x_
x_x_x_x_x_
```

La idea es poder hacer n x n casillas y obtener el resultado que menciono arriba, que siempre empiece por la x, pero he buscando bastante y no encuentro nada que me aclare la duda.

Agradezco me puedan guiar en qué me estoy equivocando, saludos!

Comment: Saludos. Lo que ocurre es que tu **Console.Write("x" + "__");** no imprime **X** o **guión** estás imprimiendo ambos; si los cuentas; notaras que son 5 grupos de **x__**. Te falta _decidir_ en que momento se imprime _equis_ o en cual _guión_.

Comment: Tienes alguna guía sobre cómo puedo decidir ello? o cómo lo podría codificar?

Comment: Puedes escribir _x cuando el contador sea inpar. Inténtalo y nos dices cómo te fue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una forma de resolverlo, cada fila y columna del tablero se tiene en cuenta y se elabora la siguiente tabla de la verdad

si la fila es par y la columna es par entonces se imprime X
si la fila es par y la columna es impar entonces se imprime _
si la fila es impar y la columna es par entonces se imprime _
si la fila es impar y la columna es impar entonces se imprime X

Este codigo es una probable solucion, sin usar ninguna subrutina y la menor cantidad de IFs

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayTablero.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayTablero.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if(i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if(j == 0 || j % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("x");
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    Console.Write("_");
                    continue;
                }
                
                if(j == 0 || j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("_");
                    continue;
                }

                Console.Write("x");                 
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que haría para simplificar la lógica seria tener `2 for` para imprimir el cuadrado y después una variable `bool` para ir alternando escribir `x` o `_`, eso ahorraria muchas variables que no son necesarias, de esta forma puedes agregar otras validaciones que necesites según lo que te solicite el ejercicio:

```
static int n = 5;
public static void Main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        bool x = i % 2 == 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            // Uso de operador ternario, es como un if que funciona en una línea
            Console.Write(x ? "x" : "_");
            // Se cambia la variable booleana por su contrario
            x = !x;
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
}
```

> Por si no estas familiarizado con el operador ternario, es una forma simple de evaluar una lógica y se compone por 2 signos `? :`, en este ejemplo evaluó si `x` es `true` se ejecuta la primera parte que es pasar el texto `x` a imprimir a consola y si es `false` se pasa el segundo texto que contiene el guion bajo.

Si necesitas que fuese igual al código que presentas, solo habría que modificar el for con la lógica del operador ternario:

```
static int n = 5;

public static void Main() {
    if(n > 10 || n <= 0)
    {
        n = 5;
    }
    
    int a = n;
    int b = n;
    int[,] arrayTablero = new int[a, b];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayTablero.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        bool x = i % 2 == 0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayTablero.GetLength(1); j++)
        { 
            Console.Write(x ? "x" : "_");
            x = !x;
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
  
}
```